# How to implement Equalizer in Android2.1?

Tags: android, equalizer

I want to implement Equalizer for android 2.1, how to implement Equalizer in android 2.1? Can anyone give me any sample code or reference or idea for that?

Comment: Equalizer e = new Equalizer(); e.setVisible(true);

Comment: Equalizer class is available for API level 9, which is for android 2.3. I have to implement for android 2.1 i.e api level 7.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way is to use an external library, like ffmpeg. It requires to compile it using the NDK (because it's written in C), and then using it via JNI links.
I've been trying that for the past 3 (full) days, and if you don't know anything about C, it's just awful...