# How to implement equalizer in Android 2.1?

Tags: java, android, audio, equalizer

I know this has been asked earlier but I was not able to find much needed information.

I have implemented equalizer in 2.3.
But I want to implement it it in 2.1

There are 2 ways I came across:

1. Either import the java library code from 2.3 to 2.1. But I do not have much hope with this.
2. Or, use JNI & Android NDK and use some out of box C/C++ libraries. (Please suggest are there any libraries available)

If any other solution is viable then please suggest.

Comment: Note that the Android SDK does not include the `javax.sound` API, which is what the tag [tag:javasound] is referring to.  Tag removed.

Comment: Impossible on 2.1. You need at least 2.3 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in [How to implement Equalizer in Android2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261248/how-to-implement-equalizer-in-android2-1?rq=1) you will need to implement your own signal processing in native code with JNI